# How to check if the result of a nodejs function?

Tags: node.js

I'm completely new to nodejs.

So I'm using puppeteer to call a webpage, I want to check if Jupyter exists on the webpage.

```
await page.evaluate((sel) => {
    if (typeof Jupyter == 'undefined') {
        jupyterundefined = true;
        return;
    } else {
        Jupyter.notebook.clear_all_output();
    }
}, 'dummy');

await page.waitFor(60000);
if(jupyterundefined){
   //do something else
```

It seems that the await function doesn't change the jupyterundefined variable, because it's asyn. But how can I check if it returns with the return I have there?

Comment: It might be a good idea to rephrase your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [page.evaluate(pageFunction[, ...args])](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) is returning a `Promise` that can hold a value, I would advise you to use it.

Like :

```
const isJupyterUndefined = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
    // === void 0 is the same as typeof undefined
    if (Jupyter === void 0) {
        return true;
    }

    Jupyter.notebook.clear_all_output();

    return false;
}, 'dummy');

await page.waitFor(60000);

if (isJupyterUndefined){
   //do something else
```